# Sync-WDSite Web Application Physical Path Parameter

Tags: powershell, iis

I've written a script which syncs sites between IIS Servers. All my website got synced without an error, but one site (which is of course the site which matters the most) gets a strange error.

the following code-part synchronizes the sites:

```
$spp = $path.Get_Item($Name)
$publishsettings = Get-WDPublishSettings -FileName $_.FullName
$sync = Sync-WDSite $Name $Name -sitephysicalpath $spp `
                                        -SourcePublishSettings $publishsettings `
                                        -IncludeApppool `
                                        -WarningAction Continue `
                                        -sourcesettings $settings `
                                        -ErrorAction Continue `
                                        -destinationsettings $settings `
                                        -debug
```

the error I get is the following (the error is in german, but I tried to translate it into english):

```
Sync-WDSite : The parameter 'Web Application Physical Path Parameter' was already defined.
In C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\wdeploy.ps1:236 Zeichen:17
+         $sync = Sync-WDSite $Name $Name -sitephysicalpath $spp `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Sync-WDSite], DeploymentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.SyncSite
```

I have absolutely no idea where this comes from.

Note that I used the `-debug` Parameter to see each step the cmdlet does. the error occurs at the stage where the other sites gathered information about the site (which site is it, which apppool does it use etc.)

Thanks!

Edit:

Additional Info:
The Publish Settings File for each site has the exact same structure and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
  <publishProfile
    publishUrl="https://server:port/msdeploy.axd"
    msdeploySite="Sitename"
    destinationAppUrl="http://anysiteurl.domain.com:port/"
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    profileName="Default Settings"
    publishMethod="MSDeploy"
    userName="server\wdeployadmin"
    userPWD="***"
    msdeployAllowUntrustedCertificate="True"
    agentType="wmsvc"
    useNTLM="False"/>
</publishData>
```

Edit:

Full Error Message as requested by Martin:

```
writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: Der Parameter 'Web Application Physical Path
                        Parameter' wurde bereits definiert.
                           bei Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.Add(DeploymentSyncParameter
                        parameter)
                           bei Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.WDeployCmdletBase.ProcessUserCmd()
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Sync-WDSite], DeploymentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.SyncSite
ErrorDetails          : Der Parameter 'Web Application Physical Path Parameter' wurde bereits definiert.

InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\wdeploy.ps1: Zeile 245
                        bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\wdeploy.ps1: Zeile 232
                        bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

Comment: Is the usage of `$Name $Name` twice normal?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli yes. first one is source-sitename and second is destination-sitename

Comment: Can you provide us the full error information using `$error[0] | fl * -force`? You can also send me the german message :-)

Comment: @MartinBrandl Hi Martin, I just updated my question with the full error info :-)!

Comment: Hm, I would try to use `msdeploy.exe -verb:sync` to check whether the error is related to the `Sync-WDSite` or whether it has to do something with the website...

Comment: @MartinBrandl , thanks for the hint. it works with the msdeploy.exe tool. So the error lies within sync-wdsite itself, which is very strange because every site except this one got deployed. hmpf.

Comment: Thats realy strange and unfortunately I don't have any idea how this happen. Anyhow, I added the hint with msdeploy.exe as an answer since its provides a workaround. Maybe you can live with it?

Comment: @MartinBrandl danke trotzdem! feel free to vote for my issue (see my answer) thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `msdeploy.exe -verb:sync` instead of the `Sync-WDSite` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin pointed out in the comments, this is a bug inside the `sync-wdsite` cmdlet itself. I reported it to Microsoft and hope they will fix this bug (even though I don't have that much faith in it). Feel free to vote for my issue! https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/15756139-web-deploy-snap-in-bug-report

With this command the site got deployed without any errors:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb=sync 
             -source:contentpath="Sitename",
                     computerName=https://Server:Port/msdeploy.axd?site=SITENAME,
                     userName=deploy,
                     password=PASSWORD,
                     authType=basic
             -dest:contentpath="D:\inetpub\path",computerName=localhost 
             -allowUntrusted
```

if you want to do this inside PowerShell, do something like:

```
$msdeployPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'

[string[]]$msdeployFolderSyncArgs = @(
    "-verb:sync",
     "-source:contentpath='Sitename',
                     computerName=https://Server:Port/msdeploy.axd?site=SITENAME,
                     userName=deploy,
                     password=PASSWORD,
                     authType=basic"
     "-dest:contentpath='D:\inetpub\path',computerName=localhost 
      -allowUntrusted"
)

$iex = Invoke-Expression "$msdeployPath $msdeployFolderSyncArgs"
```